# How to remove fullwidth tab in createMaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm having a hard time how to remove the fullwidth tab in createMaterialTopTabNavigator. I'm using this library ***https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/***

**Current output:**
[image]

**Expected output:**
[image]

I appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
<Tab.Navigator
    tabBarOptions={{
      style: { alignItems: 'flex-start' },
      tabStyle: { alignItems: 'center', width: 100 },
      indicatorStyle: { width: 100 },
    }}>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

See [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/not-fullwidth)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I solved this problem just by adding tabStyle: { width: 'auto', marginHorizontal: 20 } :)

Comment: But that would hide the bottom indicator I guess.